# perl regexp {min,max} - which scenario reported

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a way to decipher which scenario is being reported by match `$&` when regexp searches for a pattern `/[XY]{15,20}[WZ]{10,15}[XY]{15,20}/g` in a string that has mutliple matches for the regexp?

I'm trying to avoid combinatorics of:

```
[XY]{15}[WZ]{10}[XY]{15}
[XY]{15}[WZ]{10}[XY]{16}
[XY]{15}[WZ]{10}[XY]{17}
...
[XY]{16}[WZ]{10}[XY]{15}
[XY]{17}[WZ]{10}[XY]{15}
...
```

from which I would know which scenario is being reported.

By scenario I mean is it: `[XY]{15}[WZ]{10}[XY]{16}` that has match in the string or is it `[XY]{16}[WZ]{10}[XY]{15}`?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you can capture groups and check their lengths.

Comment: What do you mean by a *scenario*? Can the `@-` [variable](http://p3rl.org/perlvar) help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mpapec already suggested, you just need to capture those subexpressions if you want to determine more info about them.

```
while ($string =~ /(([XY]{15,20})([WZ]{10,15})([XY]{15,20}))/g {
    my ($whole, $xy1, $wz, $xy2) = ($1, $2, $3, $4);

    print join(',', map length, ($xy1, $wz, $xy2)), "\n";
```